# Can anyone identify the classes of these Warhammer 40k ships?

Tags: spaceship, warhammer-40k

This image isn't the clearest but it's the best screenshot I could get. It's from the final cutscene of [Dawn of War 2](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0e/Warhammer_40,000_Dawn_of_War_II.jpg).

Can anyone identify the classes of each of these ships?

It can be difficult to distinguish the second or middle ship from the third when they're not moving, but there are three ships in this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So found enough references to be quite sure.

The ship in the background (the biggest one) should be an emperor class ship.
[image]

See the ship on the top left in the picture the bow is similar enough that I'm sure there. Even though the emperor class battleship is often depicted slightly differently (bow wise) it has a sensor variant to it (in the gothic tabletop game) which has exactly the same bow variant as in that one picture I posted, which looks like the bow variant in your picture.

The 2nd biggest ship (the one in the middle) should be a space marine strike cruiser
[image]

The space marine ships are the only ones with that type of bow usually (at least in an imperial or chaos fleet). I thought about a battle barge there first but the side of the bow is just too different, a strike cruiser looks more similar there.

The last one (smallest ship) is a bit hard though. Because of the small size and the weapon under its bow I would normally say a firestorm class BUT the bridge looks a bit different to how it is normally drawn, so not a 100% on that one.
[image]

Comment: Great answer, much appreciated!

Comment: No problem glad to help. I have to admit the slight differences to the normal depictions with the smaller ships made me a bit unsure at first which is why I looked up the pictures of all other ships that had similar outlines but in the end strike cruiser and firestorm were the most similar (and I take the slight differences as artistic interpretation on the artist(s) the dawn of war 2 guys had hired)

Answer (score -1):

It's very hard to tell the sizes because there is no way to judge how far apart the vessels are.But as a W.A.G.I would would say the middle ship is a battle barge [astrate vessel].The nearest is most probably a frigate'and the far one a battleship. [I couldn't tell you what makes.]

Comment: You're a [WAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAGs)? Cool! Who's the lucky footballer?